# Can multi 'Add Filter' in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, filter, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I need to filter the screen name with the App version but Firebase analytics doesnot allow me to use multi add filter. Any help?

Please see the below screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating an audience lets you select multiple conditional filters. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en